# BuddyPress: hook to add new profile fields and groups

Tags: buddypress

I am writing a plugin that adds additional profile group and some fields in it when activated. I am using basic `$wpdb` functions to insert new rows into **bp_xprofile_groups** and **bp_xprofile_fields**

So the whole process looks very lame:

1. I add new row to **bp_xprofile_groups**;
2. I get ID of that row (*WHERE name = 'New Group Name'*);
3. I use these ID to insert new rows to **bp_xprofile_fields**

Some fields are options so in total I make 5 SQL queries just to create 1 group field and 4 option fields with 2 checkboxes in that field group.

I would like to make it using BuddyPress hooks. I found what I need:

`xprofile_insert_field_group($args)` and `xprofile_insert_field($args)`

so it looks like this:

```
$args = array(
    'name'           => 'Test',
    'description'    => '',
    'can_delete'     => '0'
    );
xprofile_insert_field_group( $args );
```

and then I am suppose to use xprofile_insert_field() but I do not know ID of a group I just created to use in field_group_id:

```
$args = array(
    'field_group_id'           => ?????,
    'parent_id'    => '',
    'type'     => 'textbox',
    ...
    ...
    );
xprofile_insert_field( $args );
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Well seems like not many people are digging into BP so here is the solution I found.

To add a new field group using BP hooks:

```
// Create new Field Group       
$group_args = array(
     'name' => 'Social Networks'
     );
$group_id = xprofile_insert_field_group( $group_args ); // group's ID
```

To add some fields to this new group:

```
// Insert New Field
xprofile_insert_field(
    array (
           field_group_id  => $group_id,
           name            => 'Twitter',
           can_delete      => false, // Doesn't work *
           field_order  => 1,
           is_required     => false,
           type            => 'textbox'
    )
);
```

I think there is currently a bug in BP. `can_delete = 0` means you cannot delete something (ie field or group), but no matter what you pass to `xprofile_insert_field()` it is going to be `can_delete = 1`.